# Ldap authentication in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I´m trying to authenticate users in ASP .Net MVC with ldap, but it isn´t working. I´m running wireshark to see if IIS is at least connecting to the LDAP server, but it´s not connecting.

I have an SQL database for the web, and then I want to authenticate users with a LDAP server.

Here is my Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://IP:PORT/OU=...,DC=..."/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection"
          connectionString="Pipe=MySQL;
                            Protocol=pipe;
                            Server=localhost;
                            Database=My DB;
                            User Id=My User;
                            Password=My Password;
                            "
          providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, 
                 Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/"
             autogenerateschema="true"/>

        <add name="ADMembership"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,
               System.Web,
               Version=2.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral,
               PublicToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
             connectionUsername="LDAP User name"
             connectionPassword="LDAP Password" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, 
                 Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             name="MySqlProfileProvider"
             applicationName="/"
             connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection"
             autogenerateschema="true"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection"
             applicationName="/"
             name="MySqlRoleProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, 
                 Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             autogenerateschema="true"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show us the code, how you are communicating with AD ?

Comment: It´s simply Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
I´ve found the error, but I don´t know how to solve it. The problem is in the binding. The binding name is Domain\username, and it should be only username. But the connection string is OK with Domain\username...
So I need in Web.config connectionUsername="domain\username", but in the user validation only send "username". How can I do this? (I do Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password), the username without domain... )